# find the web locator(css or xpath) if a row in a table, which has values with certain pattern in columns x and y

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I have a website page to test automate using Selenium. There is a table with multiple rows. I am interested in clicking a row, with column, x having a value "Ready" and column, y having 'userId' and a date 'mm/dd/yyyy' together. BTW, all the rows and cells are made up of `<div>` elements

I am able to locate the cell having a value "Ready" as 
`// div[text()='Ready']` 
which returns n such cells in N rows. Probably I can get these rows as a List by calling

```
WebDriver.getElements("//div[text()='Ready'])
```

But I have further inquiry to do. Like I need to locate some other cell in the same row(s) with 'user Id' string and a date 'mm/dd/yyyy' included in  a same cell.

This second part is what I am not clear about, how to !

Any help, please ! Here is my html markup.

```
<div role="row" row-index="3" row-id="6" comp-id="50" class="ag-row ag-row-odd ag-row-level-0 ag-row--ready ag-row-focus" style="height: 84px; transform: translateY(252px);  ">
  <div tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" comp-id="51" col-id="name" class="ag-cell ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-cell-with-height ag-cell-no-focus tu-cursor-pointer ag-cell-value ag-column-hover" style="width: 674px; left: 0px; ">
    <ng-component _nghost-c1="" class="center-table">
      <div _ngcontent-c1="" class="extract-name center-table__cell">
        <div _ngcontent-c1="" class="font-bold">PRASAD-FEB-04-215PM-EXTRACT_TEST</div>
        <div _ngcontent-c1="" class="extract-name__description"></div>
      </div>
    </ng-component>
  </div>
  <div tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" comp-id="52" col-id="0" class="ag-cell ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-cell-with-height font-bold ag-cell-value ag-cell-focus" style="width: 200px; left: 674px; ">**`Ready`**</div>
  <div tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" comp-id="53" col-id="createDate" class="ag-cell ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-cell-with-height ag-cell-no-focus ag-cell-value" title="2019-02-04 20:19:51.528" style="width: 200px; left: 874px; ">
    <ng-component>**02/04/2019**</ng-component>
  </div>
  <div tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" comp-id="54" col-id="lastRun" class="ag-cell ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-cell-with-height ag-cell-no-focus tu-cursor-pointer ag-cell-value" style="width: 200px; left: 1074px; ">
    <ng-component _nghost-c2="" class="center-table">
      <!---->
      <div _ngcontent-c2="" class="last-run center-table__cell">
        <div _ngcontent-c2="">**`pnutala`**</div>
        <div _ngcontent-c2="">**`02/04/2019`**</div>
      </div>
    </ng-component>
  </div>
  <div tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" comp-id="55" col-id="1" class="ag-cell ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-cell-with-height ag-cell-no-focus tu-cursor-pointer ag-cell-value" style="width: 160px; left: 1274px; ">
      <i class="fa fa-copy"></i> <span>Clone</span>
  </div>
  <div tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" comp-id="56" col-id="params" class="ag-cell ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-cell-with-height ag-cell-no-focus ag-cell-value" style="width: 387px; left: 1434px; ">
    <dhu-preview-list>
      <dhu-preview-info _nghost-c3="" class="center-table">
        <!----><!----><!----><!----><!----><!----><!---->
        <div _ngcontent-c3="" class="center-table__cell">
          <div _ngcontent-c3="">~4,000,000</div>
          <div _ngcontent-c3="">JUN 2016</div>
        </div>
        <!---->
        <div _ngcontent-c3="" class="center-table__cell">
           <button _ngcontent-c3="" cdk-overlay-origin="" class="no-border pull-right" type="button"><i _ngcontent-c3="" aria-hidden="true" class="fa tufa-angle-down"></i></button>
        </div>
        <!---->
      </dhu-preview-info>
    </dhu-preview-list>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please share html here.I guess within that cell you 'SPAN' tag in html?

Comment: Edited the question with html mark up for just one row ! BTW, because this is an angular website, I am using ngWebDriver which takes care of bridge between angular and Selenium. Please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here xpath examples contains "Ready" text:

```
//div[@role='row' and ./div[contains(.,'Ready')]]
//div[contains(.,'Ready')]/ancestor::div[@role='row'][1]
//div[@col-id='0' and contains(.,'Ready')]/ancestor::div[@role='row'][1]
```

Update with username and date in `lastRun` cell:

```
//div[@role='row' and ./div[contains(.,'Ready')] and ./div[@col-id='lastRun' and contains(.,'pnutala') and contains(.,'02/04/2019')]]
```

The `Status` is the 2nd column in the row and the `UserId` is the 4nd column in the row, use column index make more strict to find the row.

```
//find row by status and userid
//div[@role='row' and ./div[2][contains(., 'Ready')] and ./div[4][contains(., 'pnutala')]]

// find row by status and userid and date
//div[@role='row' and ./div[2][contains(., 'Ready')] and ./div[4][contains(., 'pnutala')][contains(.,'02/04/2019')]]
```

Comment: This works so far to identify the row with one of the cell having a value 'Ready' , but the next part is important where I am having the difficulty. Please read the question completely.

Comment: Looks like based on the business situation, whenever a row exists with status 'Ready', there ought to be a userId. In this case 'pnutala'. So I can search for a row having 'Ready' status and LastRun as containing 'userId' which is 'pnutala' here. Like **//div[@role='row' and ./div[contains(.,'pnutala')]]**